# Yearling Badge ??

Tags: discussion

How come 3 of our friends have yearling badge?

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/badges/52/yearling?userid=549

Comment: We invented time travel. But sshh! :)

Comment: James u **promised** to keep your mouth shut bout this! Last time i give u a ride in my Delorean... ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think when users get migrated, all user data is migrated, myself I have 96 days, 11 consecutive and my user id is the same.

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: But how come only 3 users were migrated?? or is it still happening?

Comment: @Shoban, oh i see now, you need to get 200 rep before you get the badge